# How to achieve smooth scrolling without choppy movement inUIColletionview?

Tags: ios

I am using UICollectionViewCusomLayout to display EPG data. I am facing issue with smooth scrolling. When scroll reaches to the end, colletionview cells moves slowly and jerk movement is visible.
Its helpful to know how to achieve smooth scrolling without choppy movement?

Comment: share some code .

Comment: Are you calling any API when scroll reach to the end or have you displaying any images from server?

Comment: I am using scrollviewdelegate. in that i am using scrollViewDidScroll api method.

Comment: No i am not using any images. from the sqlite database i am taking the information and displaying to the collectionviewcell.

Comment: Going to need to see some code here to help, some threading will help here but depends what you are doing in CellForItemAtIndexPath/willDisplayCell or even your 'prepareForReuse' in your custom cell. Drop some code, tag me in :)

Comment: @theiOSDude  In cellForItemAtIndexPath i am assigning value to the lable like cell.cellLable.text=arr[indexpath.row]; and i am calculating the cell size in custom collectionview class.

Comment: how are you "calculating the cell size in custom collectionview class. "? @savita

Comment: based on the event duration. @theiOSDude